Image not showing from database in view
I just uploaded my laravel project to the server and images are not displayed in view file only data uploaded with image appears.
Below is my controller that i used to store the image.
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Lost;
use App\Models\User;

class LostController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function display(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'location'=>'required',
            'message'=>'required',
            'contact'=>'required|numeric|min:6',
            'imogi'=>'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:5048'
           
        ]);

        $newImageName = time() . '-' . $request->name . '.' . $request->imogi->extension();
        $request->imogi->move(public_path('images'), $newImageName);


        $Lost = new Lost;
    
        $Lost->name = $request->input('name');
        $Lost->location = $request->input('location');
        $Lost->message = $request->input('message');
        $Lost->contact = $request->input('contact');
        $Lost->imogi = $newImageName;
        $Lost->save();
        /*
        return redirect()->back();
        */
        return back()->with('success', 'Send successfully.');

    }
}

Below is the view file that i used to upload the image to the database.
@extends('layouts.app')



@section('content')

<div class="container">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

        <div class="col-md-8">

        <h5 style="text-align: center;"><label style="color:#3490dc;">Post</label> <label style="color:white;"> Lost or Found</label></h5>

        <form action="founds" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

         @csrf

         @if (session('success'))

                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">

                                {{ session('success') }}

                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">

                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

                            </button>

                            </div>

                        @endif

     <!--<img class="center-block" src="/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}" style="width: 80px; border-radius: 20%; float:center;"> -->

         <div class="form-group">

    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:24px"></i> <label style="color:white;">Name</label></label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="name" value="{{ auth()->user()->name }}" readonly>

  </div>



  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size:24px"></i> <label style="color:white;">Location</label></label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control @error('location') is-invalid @enderror" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="location">

    <span style="color: red;"><small>@error('location'){{$message}}@enderror</small></span>

    <small style="color:white;">Give the location where the item was found/lost</small>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:24px"></i> <label style="color:white;">Item details</label></label>

    <textarea type="text" class="form-control @error('message') is-invalid @enderror"  id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="2" name="message" placeholder=""></textarea>

    <span style="color: red;"><small>@error('message'){{$message}}@enderror</small></span>

    <small style="color:white;">Provide the details of the found/lost item</small>

  </div>



  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size:24px"></i> <label style="color:white;">Contacts</label></label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control @error('contact') is-invalid @enderror"  id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="contact">

    <span style="color: red;"><small>@error('contact'){{$message}}@enderror</small></span>

    <small style="color:white;">Provide your contacts here</small>

  </div>

  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1"><i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-picture-o" style="font-size:24px"></i> <label style="color:white;"></label></label>

  <form action="{{ route('file.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            @csrf

            <div class="row">

  

                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <input type="file" class="form-control @error('imogi') is-invalid @enderror"  name="imogi">

                </div>

            </div>

            <small style="color:white;">Select the image of the found/lost item</small>

            <br/>

            <br/>

            <button type="submit" style="text-align: center; background-color:#3490dc; color:white;" class="btn">Post</button>

        </form>

        <br/>

</form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

@include('footer')

@endsection

This is the view where i am trying to retrieve the image, the image was showing perfectly before i deploy the project. I don`t know what i am doing wrong.
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<div class="container">

   <<div class="row justify-content-center">

       <div class="col-md-8">

                <!--Ad-->

<!--<div style="color:black; text-align:center;" class="alert" role="alert">

<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">

    <span aria-hidden="true"><small style="color:silver"><small><small>Close Ad</small></small> </small></span>

  </button>

  <br/>

  <h6 class="alert-heading"><a href="https://www.cbs.co.ls/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <span class="badge badge-secondary"> Ad</span> <small>CBS</small> </a> <a href="https://www.cbs.co.ls/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="btn btn-secondary">Learn more</a></h6>

  <p style="color:grey;"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i> <small>We are a highly competitive IT player with customers across the globe. <label style="color:white;"> <b> Technology that transforms business.</b></label></small><img id="border-wrap" class="imogi" style="width: 40px; height:40px; border-radius: 20%" src="{{url('/img/cbs.png')}}"

        alt=""></p>

</div>

<br/>-->

<!--end Ad-->

       <h4 style="color:silver;">Lost and Found</h4>

       <div style="background-color:#162238; color:white;" class="card">

  <div class="card-body">

  <form class="form-inline" type="get" action="{{url('/search_lost')}}" role="search" method="get">

                    <input id="search-input" type="search" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">  

                    <div class="input-group-append">

                    <button type="submit" style="text-align: center; background-color:#131c2d; color:#3490dc;" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                    </div>

                    </form>

  </div>

</div>

<br/>

        @foreach($info as $inf)

        <div style="background-color:#162238; color:white;" class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">

  <div class="row g-0">

    <div class="col-md-4">

      <img src="{{asset('images/' . $inf->imogi)}}" alt="" />
      

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">

      <div class="card-body">

      <div style="text-align: right;">

     <small><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ $inf->created_at->format('l, d F, Y') }}</small>

      </div>

      <br/>

              <!--LIVEWIRE online status-->

              @if($inf->isOnline())

              <small><div class="circle"></div></small>

              @else

             <small><div  class="ocircle"></div></small> 

             @endif 

             <br/>

               

      <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a style="color:white;" href="">{{$inf->name}} </a></h5>

      <i class="fa fa-clock-o" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> <small style="color:#3490dc;"> posted {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($inf->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</small><br/>

        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> <small>{{$inf->location}}</small> <br/> <small><i class="fa fa-phone" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i></small> <small>{{$inf->contact}}</small>

       

       <hr color=3490dc>

        <p class="card-text">

        <p><label style="color:#3490dc;"></label> {{$inf->message}}</p>

        </p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>



<br/>

@endforeach

<!--{{ $info->links() }}-->


{!! $info->withQueryString()->links('pagination::bootstrap-5') !!}

        </div>

                <!--Ad-->

<div style="color:black; text-align:center;" class="alert" role="alert">

<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">

    <span aria-hidden="true"><small style="color:silver"><small><small>Close Ad</small></small> </small></span>

  </button>

  <br/>

  <h6 class="alert-heading"><a href="https://www.alliance.co.ls/" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> <span class="badge badge-secondary"> Ad</span> <i style="color:#3490dc" class="fa fa-globe" style="font-size:24px"></i> <small>Alliance</small> </a> </h6>

  <p style="color:grey;"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i> <small> Lesotho based Insurance providing Short-Term Commercial and Personal Insurance, Funeral. <label style="color:white;"></small><img id="border-wrap" class="imogi" style="width: 40px; height:40px; border-radius: 20%"  src="{{url('/img/alla.jpg')}}"

        alt=""></p>

</div>

<br/>

<!--end Ad-->

    </div>

</div>

@include('footer')

@endsection

I will appreciate any help thank you all in advance. 


Have you checked that your file is uploaded properly? In which director file is uploaded?hav you run this command php artisan storage:link

The project is now online...and it was uploaded working properly not untill it was online
